Azure Data Factory : Error 409 when trying to unzip files in blob storage
I have compressed files in blob storage and I'm trying to unzip them with an Azure Data Factory activity.
Each compressed file is composed of compressed folders inside. So when I try to unzip, it has to unzip in cascade.
This works very well with files in blob storage (storage account gen2), but recently we've switched to hierarchical namespace mode. Before that, it worked with virtual folders (the folders didn't really exist, it was the blobs that had names like folder/subfolder/file.txt), now with this hierarchical namespace mode, I systematically get a 409 error in the Azure Data Factory activity.
Do you know where the problem might be coming from and what the solution might be?

As per the documentation,

The 409 error can occur for multiple reasons like conflicts or due to lease policies or when the Blob content is too long.

You can go through this documentation and re-check whether any of your approach involves the above operations.
For me, I got the above error in below scenarios.

when I am trying to delete a Blob file when the file snapshots are present.

It got resolved after deleting the Blob snapshots. So, when you are trying to unzip the file again, there may be blob snapshots for the existing blobs. Make sure you delete all the blob snapshots before unzipping.

When trying to copy data to a target container which was deleted. In this case, you can first try to copy this to a new container with new name, if it works, you can confirm the issue is with the container deletion.

You can try enabling the soft delete for blobs and containers to resolve this issue.


Apart from these two reasons, make sure you cross-check all the scenarios that were given for this error in the above documentation.
